# Is it possible to make a website which can be accessable from only some specific locations?

Tags: web

I am planning to make a small blog website which can be accessed from our state only.Is there any way to reach this goal.Please help me out.

Comment: Have you come accross [MaxMind's GeoIP service](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/)? Whilst not infallible it's a good start.

Comment: Please edit and add more information.  What kind of web-server, firewall, service provider your have?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that - simple as that.

You can try a few things to raise a bar, but a determined attacker will be able to overcome the restriction.

- Depending on your definition of state you can try a simple firewall. It can be easy if it's a range of IP addresses. But it may be easy to overcome this as well with VPN
- You can add authentication and only allow users that can pass authentication. You need to have a process to grant login details only to specific users

Comment: I just worded up an almost identical answer - instead of the firewall idea with a range of IP addresses I would be more inclined to go with a geo-location service that will do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: @lukkea I know Netflix is doing something similar - not very successfully though as people just use VPN to emerge in whatever country they want to get service from (usually US).

Comment: is there any alternative way or any suggestion to meet my requirements

Comment: @pranabesh not that I'm aware of.

Comment: thanks for helping me.